# Unable to add docker repository to Ubuntu 18.10 - cosmic

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Trying to install Docker in Ubuntu 18.10(cosmic). I am unable to add docker repository if I execute below comand:
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

Below is error detail:

```
 Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
    Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
    Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu Bionic InRelease         
    Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease         
    Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease        
    Err:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic Release            
      404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2098:7e00:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
    Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease         
    Err:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu Bionic Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2098:7e00:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: T**he repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.**
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
    E: **The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu Bionic Release' does not have a Release file.**
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Looks like your pat sources are out of date, update them.

Comment: [Gábor Bakos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1502148/g%c3%a1bor-bakos), [LuFFy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087247/luffy), [Matt Bierner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306149/matt-bierner), [Matt Raines](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5024519/matt-raines), [Umair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3548046/umair) - This question is legitimate as I am running through the same problem - I just download Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic and am facing it. I even installed docker through snap but none the less, other issues arose. Please, reopen it.

Comment: 1. https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/442 -
2. https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-10/ -

Comment: Bad news is that Docker hasn't been released for Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)...

Comment: Good news is that you can use the Docker for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver), till new update rolls out.

Comment: $ `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable" && sudo apt update && sudo apt install docker-ce`